# Spark sql select and reduce in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

So, I have a class called UserBehavior like:

```
public class User_Behavior {
private String userName;
private String itemId;
private double bhvCnt;}
```

I created a Dataset from Dataset and ,**wanted to select itemId and bhvCnt, then reduce all bhvCnt that has same itemId together**,I use Java so I wrote code like:

```
Dataset<Row> selected=dataset.select("itemId","bhvCnt");
    selected.reduce(new ReduceFunction<Row>() {
        @Override
        public Row call(Row v1, Row v2) throws Exception {
            return new Row(v1.getAs("itemId"),v1.getDouble(1)+v2.getDouble(1));
        }
    });
```

But my IDE hint me that Row is abstract.

What is the right way to write the code I wanted?

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you have sample data? Instead of new Row use RowFactory.create(v1.getAs("itemId"),v1.getDouble(1)+v2.getDouble(1));

Comment: @abaghel I have data and I want a Dataset<Row> that one column represent itemId and the other represent sum of one item’s bhvCnt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupBy` on column "itemId" and `sum` on column "bhvCnt" like below.

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;

Dataset<Row> ds = selected.groupBy(col("itemId")).sum("bhvCnt");
ds.show(false);
```

**EDIT**

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum;

Dataset<Row> ds = selected.groupBy(col("itemId")).agg(sum("bhvCnt").as("sum")).sort(col("sum"));
ds.show(false);
```

Comment: Thank you, and a further question, after  sum() , I want to sort the sum, column name bhvCnt doesn't work in sort(), how can I name the column?